# How do I represent the type of an argument in a UML class diagram, when the argument is a function?

Tags: function, uml, class-diagram

For example, a class has a method `compute()` (using Python syntax and dropping the `self` argument for clarity):

```
def compute(computation_fn):
    return computation_fn(5)
```

Let's assume that `computation_fn` maps int to int. In a UML class diagram, should I write something like this?

```
+ compute(computation_fn: (num: int): int): int
```

If this has already been answered somewhere, just drop a link! I've been trying to look for an answer.

Comment: You should go with Christophe's answer. However, I would not bother too much. Since Python isn't 100% OO (which language except for Smalltallk is?) you can probably "bend" UML to your needs - as long as you document somewhere how you are bending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML does only have the basic types `Integer`, `Boolean`, `String`, `UnlimitedNatural`, and `Real`.

You can also use any class that you define in your model as type. In this regard, you can very well define a [class that corresponds to a kind of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914558/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-bunch-of-functions-in-uml),  for example `FunctionOfIntToInt`.  That's usual business in any design that uses callables.

UML may also be enriched with additional types in a profile. Very often, you'll see types of your favourite language used.  This assumes the use of a language specific profile.  But usually it's fixed type names (e.g. `Date`, `UInt8`, ...).  You could imagine a type called as `(int):int`, but this would be ambiguous in regard of UML's syntax that uses already `:`.

Unfortunately, there's nothing in UML's typing system that would allow to represent functions with arbitrary number of arguments of flexible type.  So it all depends how compliant you need to be with UML:

- Python programmers would understand any python type that you'd use in the diagram, including function types, even if it's not "pure" UML.  So this would be  pragmatic approach.  I'll recommend nevertheless to replace the `:` for the return type with `->` to avoid lexical confusion
- But if you have to go by the book, profiles don't allow for a syntax extension that would allow to compose types on the top of existing UML mechanisms. There's a workaround.  You could use an UML template class to represent functions.  The first argument would be the return type, and the remaining template arguments the argument types.  You'd then use UML's native [template binding](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/14.0/model_domains/template_binding.html) syntax to instantiate the template for typing purpose.  But I agree, it's more clumsy (even if it'd seem familiar to any user of [C++ `std::function` template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: You should use a spell checker ;-)

Comment: I always imagine you sitting on a bike and tapping answers into your mobile device xD

Comment: @qwerty_so you made my day :-) I’m always focused on the road when on my bike. But I type a couple of answers on my mobile (but I have not this excuse for this one) ;-)