# How to model a file being compiled for different execution environments in UML?

Tags: uml, deployment-diagram

I have a matlab function that is used in three different ways:

- From within Matlab (.m)
- As a .NET library (.dll)
- As a standalone binary (.exe)

This makes three different artifacts deployed on three different execution environments (or nodes in general). From the .m-file I create the .dll and .exe using Matlab MCC (compiler).

In my current model the files are left unrelated. How would I model that the .dll and .exe are compiled from .m using MCC?

Also, how should I relate the interfaces exposed by each? The environments have very different type systems.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have a component made of a function ([or a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915062/3723423)):

- The `.m` file is the source code of this function. It is therefore an artifact that manifests/embodies the abstract concept of your function in a digital format.
- At the same time the `.m` is compiled and gives a `.dll` and a `.exe` which both embody/manifest the same function but in yet different forms. Hence, all three artifacts <> the same function.
- But the `.dll` and the `.exe` also depend on the `.m`.  So you could add another dependency, that you could for example further clarify an ad-hoc stereotype (e.g. `<<generated from>>`? )

[image]

The three artifacts could be deployed independently on nodes (including the `.m` file which could be directly executed on a matlab execution environment nested in a node).  If you want to show this on the same diagram you could:

- Show the deployment with nested artifacts directly on nodes, and adding the dependencies in the diagram.
- But you could as well keep artifacts apart and use the `<<deploy>>` dependency notation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a reified `Compilation` class that has an association with `Source File`, an association with an abstract `Compiler Output File`, and an association with `Compiler`. Create two subclasses of `Compiler Output File`: one called `Dynamic Linked Library File` and one called `Executable File`. This pattern makes explicit how compilation happens.