# How to represent a function/method type in a UML class diagram

Tags: uml, function-pointers

Is there a standard way to represent a named function type in a UML class diagram?

By *named function type*, I mean a function or method type with a certain signature (parameters, return type, possibly generic parameters), to which an alias has been assigned, which is then referenced throughout the class model.

The concept is known in various different languages, e.g.:

C#:

```cs
public delegate string GetTextFunc(int value, bool modify);
```

TypeScript:

```js
type GetTextFunc = (value: number, modify: boolean) => string;
```

(Yes, there are differences in implementation, but for the sake of a class model, these should be irrelevant.)

How do I represent such a type in a UML class diagram? As so far, I could not find any standardized answer, I have thought about shoehorning them into a class element while making use of custom stereotypes to express the meaning, e.g:

[image: function type as UML class element]

**However, in this question, I am explicitly looking for *the standardized way* to do this, if there is any.**

Comment: I guess that these are _syntactical sugar_ and inventions of just compiler builders.

Comment: @qwerty_so: Arguably, this applies to most of the high-level language concepts that UML focuses on, including inheritance and the notion of classes and interfaces overall.

Comment: I would not say _most_, but probably you have to go with your stereotype constructs. Just see if someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to represent functions or function types in UML.

But a function type describes a class of functions, so a class is definitively the way to go.  The use of a non-standard  stereotype `«function»` would the facilitate to distinguish this very special kind of class (see also this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63915062/3723423) on a related but not identical question).

Regarding the parameters, your way to go could be defended. However, semantically it is questionable since they are not really public properties, and exist only for the time of one specific invocation. A more consistent approach would be to have no attributes (except perhaps private static ones, as these are the only ones who may stand for a function independently of the calls) and use instead a pseudo operation (like `operator()(...)` in C++)  with the exact signature of your function. Semantically this would be consistant with the use of inheritance between a particular  function and its function type. It would also be consistent with all the semantics of sequence diagrams.

Keep in mind that operations are named elements, so you would have to name the pseudo-operation, even if in your code there would be no such name.

Comment: Thank you, this is quite helpful. The only concern I see with this suggestion is that if e.g. one of the parameters is typed to another class from the same class diagram, just mentioning the class name as a parameter of some method-like pseudo operator rather than actually seeing a reference edge in the graph makes the connection much less visually obvious, and by extension, renders the diagram much less helpful IMO. But then, this is a general problem in the UML class notation, so I can't really hold it against this particular solution.

Comment: I am not sure I get the intention behind the last paragraph in your answer. The fact that the function type is named is the premise of my question. If the type were anonymous in code (which, in the languages I work with, would invariably mean it is not defined in a reusable manner, but e.g. inline right where it is used), I would not need a specific notation element and just write it inline in the field of the UML class, as well.

Comment: @F-H regarding your first comment, this is indeed a general uml concern. However, you could perfectly highlight the situation with a dependency from the function type class to the class used as parameter. You could even stereotype this dependency with non-standard «parameter» and «return type». This would give a very clear picture and at the same time benefit from the consistency with UML semantics.  (a step further could be tonise tagged values to even document the name of the parameter, but this would be redundant, difficult to maintain and overkill)

Comment: @F-H indeed I read your question on a small smartphone screen and thought that you had some anonymous cases, whereas now I realize that they were named and you even refer explicitly to named types. So my last paragraph is only relevant for the name of the pseudo operation. I edited accordingly.