# UML class diagram of software timer

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have header file of software timers. And now I try make class diagram for this.

But I not sure what this diagram correctly ...

```c
typedef enum {
    SWTMR_IDLE,
    SWTMR_RUN,
    SWTMR_DONE
} swtmr_st_t;

typedef struct swtmr_t {
    uint32_t endTime;
    uint32_t currTime;
    swtmr_md_t isTimer;
} Swtimer_t;

void SwTimer_Create(Swtimer_t *const pTIMER, const swtmr_st_t MODE, const uint32_t SET_TIME);

void SwTimer_Delete(Swtimer_t *pTimer);
void SwTimer_Set(Swtimer_t *const pTIMER, const swtmr_st_t MODE, const uint32_t SET_TIME);
swtmr_st_t SwTimer_Get_Status(Swtimer_t *const pTIMER);
uint32_t SwTimer_Get_Rest_Time(Swtimer_t *const pTIMER);
uint32_t SwTimer_Get_Time(Swtimer_t *const pTIMER);
void SwTimer_Scan(void);
```

[image]

Comment: Change “enum” to “swtmr_st_t” throughout, just like in the source code.

Comment: Though it looks like some C-language you should tag this with the actual language you used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how close you want to stay to the implementation or how abstract you are ready to go for a design perspective.

Technically speaking, in this C file, from an UML perspective there is an enumeration defined, a class without any operation, and a [bunch of free functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63914558/is-it-possible-to-visualize-a-bunch-of-functions-in-uml/63915062#63915062) that depend on the defined types.  You could then represent each function with its own class, or group all these functions in a class without attributes which represents the compilation unit,  or all at the same time in a package corresponding to the namespace of the header.

But you could as well get closer to the design intent. It seems that you went that way:  all the functions starting with the prefix `SwTimer_` ***and*** having as first argument a pointer to an `SwTimer_t` pointer are probably operations of the `SwTimer_t` type.  You could then model them together with the structure as a class.  Because you could implement the same design in C++ using a real class encapsulating all these attributes an operations.  When you do this modelling transformation, you need to decide on 2 items:

- Do you keep the `SwTimer_` prefix  (i.e. would you keep the prefix if your programming language would allow to embed it into a class) ?
- Do you show the first `SwTimer_t*` argument (i.e. the argument that makes it possible in your language to know on which object the operation shall be performed, whereas in another language this would be implicit) ?

There is no correct answer. It's just up to you to decide on the convention.

The `SwTimer_Scan()` function is a different story, because this does not perform an operation on a specific object (no pointer as argument).  If you wanted to show this as an operation of the class, you would show it as an UML static (i.e. a class operation that is performed independently of any instance).  On the diagram, you would underline it to show it's static.

Now, some details:

- there is no void return type in UML:  you just keep the function but remove the trailing `: void`
- at several places you refer in the operation signature to an enum parameter or an enum return type.  Would this work if there would be two different enumerations defined? No!  You need to use `swtmr_st_t` instead.
- same problem, everywhere you use `struct`. Please refer to the name of the class (if you keep that first argument).
- in your code there is no `state`.  In your diagram there is no attribute `isTimer`. Please check if this is typo.
- in principle there is no `uint32_t` type in UML but a type `integer`. But don't worry, it's a commonly accepted practice to use language native types in UML.  Just imagine that these are defined in another diagram.
- avoid to use `return` for the dependency.  The dependency is also true for other things than the return type;
- a very last remark.  if your `state` would indeed be a `swtmr_st_t`, you could remove it from the attribute,  replace the dependency arrow with a plain line and writing above this line, close to the enumeration, the name of the property, e.g. `state`.